# bootstrap colorpicker in bootstrap modal only works on first row of table

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I have a table with datatables.  When you click a row it opens a modal to edit that row.  In the model there is a field wit a colorpicker. (col2)

The problem I have is that the colorpicker only works when clicking on the first row of the table.

I think a solution would be to have a variable field name, but does not know how to implement this.

here the code of my modal that opens when clicking a row in the table:

```
            echo "<div class='modal fade' id='ModalEdit".$locations['id']."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>";
                    echo "<div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>";
                        echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
                            echo "<form class='form-horizontal' method='POST' action='editLocation.php'>";      
                            echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
                                echo"<h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel' >Locatie bewerken</h4>";
                            echo "</div>";

                            echo "<div class='modal-body'>  ";      

                                echo "<div class='form-group'>  ";       
                                    echo "<label for='titel' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Locatie</label>";                   
                                    echo "<input type='text' name='locatie' class='form-control' id='locatie' value='".$locations['locatie']."' >";                   
                                echo "</div>";

                                echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                                    echo "<label for='detailtitel' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Color</label>";                             
                                    echo "<input type='col2' class='form-control' id = 'col2' name='col2' value='".$locations['color']."' >";   
                                echo "</div>";

                                echo"<div class='form-group'>";                             
                                    echo"<input type='hidden' name='id' class='form-control' id='id' value='".$locations['id']."'>";
                                echo" </div>";          

                            echo"</div>";             
                            echo"<div class='modal-footer'>";
                                echo"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
                                echo"<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>";
                            echo" </div>";
                            echo"</form>";
                        echo"</div>";                   
                    echo"</div>";               
                echo"</div>";
```

And the script to load the colorpicker:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#col2').colorpicker({

        format: 'hex'
            });
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ID` to `Class`

`ID` is a `Unique`

```
echo "<input type='col2' class='form-control colorpicker' id = '' name='col2' value='".$locations['color']."' >";

$(function () {
        $('.colorpicker').colorpicker({

        format: 'hex'
            });
             });
```

**or**

Recall colorpicker `function` on bootstrap `show modal event`

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.